# incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted

Tags: intellij-idea

[I am new to java.I am writing program for pre-order tree traversal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1RRX.png)

Comment: Please post code as text rather than an image. This will help people to be able to copy-paste, edit, and search the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Stack<Tree>` rather than a `Stack` in the fifth line of `preOderIter`. This tells the compiler that the `Stack` stores `Tree`s (rather than the default `Object`) so when you do `stack.pop()` (see the line underlined in red) it knows the result is a `Tree` and not just any `Object`.